# VSTest Agent - property 'ForcedLegacyMode' in .runsettings file caused TestRunParameters nulls - how to fix this ?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest, vstest

I woluld like to add recording my tests in VSTest Runner.

I have one .testsettings file with enabled test recording and multiple .runsettings files with various custom params.

My example .runsettings:
    
      
        
      
      
        ..\TestSettings1.testsettings 
        true

From there https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx

I know that when i specify path to .testsettings into .runsettings file I have to add ForcedLegacyMode 'true' too.

But when this is set, values in TestRunParameters are nulls when I read them in ClassInitialize.

Any help ?